# Encoding a Custom Link for use outside of Salesforce?

Tags: custom-link, encoding

I would like to create a custom link to our website using Salesforce data to autofill a form, and then be able to copy and paste the link into an email or other document. It works fine to do that with the standard Custom Link features, but it's quite obvious when we copy the URL where each item in the form can be changed, and we don't want the clients to be able to edit the URL to fill out the form in their own way.

Basically, is there any way to encode a Custom Link so that it still sets the form values from the correct fields, but the client doesn't have access to change it themselves?

Thanks,
Adrian

Comment: Nice name. I don't think you will be able to obfuscate your parameters like you want, but then again, I have never tried, which is why this is a comment and not an answer. Depending on what kind of server your link points to, you could theoretically encrypt your parameters and pass in the encrypted result as a single parameter, which you then decrypt on the other side. That could still be modified though by someone determined enough.